# Use NSMutableDictionary writeToFile method that contains CLPlacemark objects

Tags: ios, nsdata, cllocationmanager, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` that contains some objects..

Between these objects I have also a `CLPlacemark`.

I would to use the method `writeToFile:pathFile atomically:YES` to salve on file but if the dictionary contains the CLPlacemark the operation fails..

How can I use the method to save if I also objects of that type?

One first idea was to convert the `CLPlacemark` to `NSData`... there are other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `CLPlacemark` objects cannot be serialized as dictionary, also if you convert it to NSData it also cannot be saved within a dictionary.

try using `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:path_to_file];`

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive the `CLPlacemark` to a `NSData`. `NSData` can be incorporated into a dictionary or property list.

Then, of course, use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to get it back.